# Difference between "upto" and "up to"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I was writing something along "... I could only read *upto* page 34" when my spell-check app Grammarly complained that I should rather use "up to".

So, what's the difference between the two and is there really any difference? Or is it that the condensation "upto" is not technically allowed?

Comment: You can use the following self-test: Does the single word say something different from the two words? If not, stay with two words. By contrast, *into* and *onto* do mean things other than *in to* and *on to*, so they work as single words.

Comment: It is not off topic - I am here as a native speaker and linguist because Microsoft Word rejected it, and I was looking for a linguistic discussion. I do not allow my non-English background students to use Grammarly because it makes things worse in my experience. I was spending time correcting one draft, only to find the next draft was worse because they had past it through Grammarly first. I don't know to what extent there are even native speakers associated with the product.

Comment: David - it is off topic here. If you read our [about] and [ask] pages you will understand this site's scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Upto*** is a misspelling of ***up to***. -- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upto)

Use *up to* with a space between the two words. Also, as [Yosef Baskin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395535/difference-between-upto-and-up-to/395536#comment937919_395535) says:

> You can use the following self-test: Does the single word say something different from the two words? If not, stay with two words. By contrast, *into* and *onto* do mean things other than *in to* and *on to*, so they work as single words.

Comment: Excellent advice - only problem is it doesn't always work. There are many words involving prepositions or particles (clitics) where spell checkers correct me away from what I regard as correct and vice-versa. And these conventions change over time. The words _into_ and _onto_ are not intrinsically different from _out of_ and _up to_ - and as a native speaker and linguist I regard _upto_ as perfectly correct when it functions. I too am here because Microsoft Word rejected it and was looking for a linguistic discussion.

Answer (score 5):

**Up to** is always two words. **Upto** isn't listed in the dictionaries.  You should always avoid it.